# How to display items from JSON file to spinner

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to display a list on a spinner from a json file in asset folder. I found a tutorial but I think my format is wrong, please help!
also, will this process take time to load to the spinner if the list has up to 300 items?

here is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayList<String> items = getFood("food.json");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.txt, items);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getBanks(String fileName) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        try {
            InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] data = new byte[size];
            is.read(data);
            is.close();
            String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

            if (jsonObject != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++) {

                  JSONArray foodList = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    if(cList != null){
                        for(int j=0; i<cList.length(); j++){
                            JSONObject fList = foodList.getJSONObject(j);
                            String food_name = foodList.getString("name");
                            String food_code = foodList.getString("code");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            je.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cList;
    }
}
```

the structure of my response, saved as food.json

```
{
  "status": "Successful",
  "data": [
    {
      "code": "11",
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Apple"
    },
    {
      "code": "22",
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Carrot"
    },
    {
      "code": "33",
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Diamonds"
    },
    {
      "code": " 44",
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Eggs"
    },
   {
      "code": "55",
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Fish"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Action was successful"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task use [jackson-jr](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jr) (Size is very small and faster than other libraries like Gson, Jasckson core ...)

Considering Performance, it is the best option than other.

---

Now let's go to the solution

**First import jackson-jr library to Your android project**

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jr:jackson-jr-objects:2.10.0'
```

**then create two model classes like this**

```
public class Food {
    private String status;
    private List<Data> data;
    private String message;

    public Food() {
    }

    //getters and setters
}

public class Data {
    private String code;
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Data() {
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Final step get data objects**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jr.ob.JSON;

private List<Data> getData() {
    List<Data> data = null;
    try {
        // give your json file as a inputstream
        //InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.food); 
        InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("food.json");
        Food bean = JSON.std.beanFrom(Food.class, is);
        data = bean.getData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return data;
}
```

You can do whatever after that using this list of Data...

---

**For passing only food names**

There are a lot of ways. Here is a simple way

in your `onCreate` method use below code

```
    List<Data> data = getData();
    List<String> foodNames = getFoodNamesFromData(data);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.txt, foodNames);
    // Your usual codes
```

and here is the `getFoodNamesFromData()` method

```
private List<String> getFoodNamesFromData(List<Data> dataList) {
    List<String> foodNames = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Data data :dataList){
        String foodName = data.getName();
        foodNames.add(foodName);
    }

    return foodNames;
}
```

Happy coding!!!

Comment: I tried above code with your food.json file and it's working fine for me. If you face any issues, feel free to comment here

Comment: Thanks for tour reply, I have an issues with R.raw.food. raw is unrecognised

Comment: I gave Json file as a raw file. You can give your own inputstream. Try `InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("food.json");`

Comment: yes this works! and its pretty fast. How do I pass only the food name to the spinner

Comment: hi, I ran into a little issue, I am trying to use a method to get the code too. the method only takes the value of the string when clicked. but the foodlist kept throwing null pointer exception

Comment: hi, I didn't get your problem. Can you post your code and error message?

Comment: ```@Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if(isSpinnerTouched){

                    selectedItem = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this " + selectedItem + "has been clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    foodCode = getCode(selectedItem);
                }
            }```

Comment: ```private String getCode(String fName) {
List<Food> data = getData();
        String code = "";
       
        for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){
            Food food = data.get(i);
            if(food.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fName)){
                code = String.valueOf(food.getCode());
                break;
            }
        }
        
        return code;

    }```

Comment: Hi...I am little busy now, Is it ok to answer later?

Comment: sure! anytime is fine

Comment: Did you have any github link of your this project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210440/discussion-between-majuran-and-chichi).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a custom class for following structure

```
{
      "code": "11",
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Apple"
}
```

So that you can use GSON library to parse json into a list using TypeToken and it'll be easy to pass to a adapter.

You can do like,

```
List<YourClass> yourClass = Gson().fromJson(json.toString(),new TypeToken<List<YourClass>>(){}.getType())
```

Comment: how do I convert to  a class please? This json file was given for a project and I dont know how to go about it

Comment: You can do something like,
```
public class YourClassName {

@SerializedName("code")
public String code;
@SerializedName("id")
public Integer id;
@SerializedName("name")
public String name;

}
```
Then you can use it to get list of json from provided json file